# Python to start the execution of a stored procedure, then exit while the query is still being executed in the database (DB2 cloud)

Tags: python, database, db2

I have a huge query to run and I want to start it with python but from the python end I do not really care about if the execution finishes or not. I want to just trigger the sql query with python and then exit, while the query still runs in the db.

I am curious if this is possible, and if so, how?

Comment: This may actually be something that is specific to the database type, to have a query run in the background. So knowing the database might actually be relevant here.

Comment: the database is a db2 public cloud instance. Let me update the question.

Comment: Also, what do you gain by quitting the Python process? Why not let it sit in the background, possibly catching an error from the query, or confirmation that it succeeded (possibly be logged to file).

Comment: The reason why I need to do this is the following: The platform we have to work on is really unstable. The pods can easily fail if a python script is running for like half an hour. So what I want to do is to start a stored procedure in db2 from python and that stored procedure will update a meta table when it finishes running (success/failure). This meta table information can be checked in every 5 or 10 seconds so we know if the execution is finished or not. This way I can avoid the pod failure to cause issues with my queries.

Comment: How long (on average) does it take your stored-procedure to complete? Depending on the duration, and on the configuration of the Db2-server instance, the stored-procedure may get cancelled if the client-connection gets closed when python quits. If your stored procedure complets within a couple of minutes this won't be a problem, I suspect. A better design should be used. You should mention if the stored procedure has any result-sets, or output parameters, or whether it uses any server-side non-Db2 libraries.